# Decimals are displaying with out rounding off

Tags: oracle, datastage

I'm moving data from one table, say A, to other table, say B, and in B table I'm seeing decimals are displaying like this

```
 1.35 As  1.3500000000000001
25.54 As 25.539999999999999
```

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to get results of both the tables.
I'm Using Datastage to move data from A to B. If I write the same in a file or dataset it's displaying correct value. 
What's the issue with Oracle sql developer. Please let me know if there is any solution to display the data as of table A.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read something on [ask] before posting a question. You can even have a look at the [tour]. Please edit your question adding some code, table strucure, data sample

Comment: There's a floating point double lurking around your conversion process somewhere.

Comment: Are the corresponding fields in both tables of the same type?

Comment: A is data type numeric with specific size/precision (or possibly even varchar)  .  Table B must have float data type.

Comment: Yes. Both the tables are having Number Data type.